# Do I absolutely have to use static variables when working with threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

As part of a personal project I am making an [IRC bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat_bot). My first attempt was to have one main class do all the work, but it is not very efficient, so I decided to separate the IRC part from the bot, making a very simple IRC client that would connect to the server, authenticate itself, join the channels and receive lines.

I can then either process each line as the IRC client receives it or put the client in a thread where it will put the lines in a queue or map (depending on what type of line it is). The thread option seems to be more appropriate and challenging.

Since the bot needs to have access to the lines received by the IRC client, I thought of putting the lines in a public static queue accessible by the bot, but that reminds me a global variables in C and I find it very odd since everyone can access this field. Is there a way I could have the IRC client do its job and the bot peaking in the lines without a public static field?

I thought of having the IRC client deliver the lines with a synchronized method so the bot is notified when a line is available.

Comment: Why not make an object that raises an event for each line received; you can pass that object (Dependency Injection) into your bot and have it subscribe to this event. Or use, pretty much the same principle, of the Publisher/Subscriber (or Observer) pattern.

Comment: The fact that the task is done in a thread changes absolutely nothing. You pass the arguments to the task (it may be a Runnable) as if it wasn't launching a thread.

Comment: RobIII Do you mean something along this http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/19335-creating-blocking-methods.html#post73716 ?

dystroy I am not sure I understand what you said, if the IRC client is run in a thread, how can it pass an argument to another instance without a static variable?

Comment: That's the prime example for a `publisher-consumer` problem. You can easily search for that term and the usual solutions. Although I'm slightly surprised what the bot is doing that a simple singlethreaded solution doesn't cut it. It's not as if it was getting thousands of lines every second.

Comment: Exactly, the bot works perfectly fine like that, but processing each line as it arrives seemed like a wrong way to handle things, I thought it could be better if the IRC client worked alone in a thread gathering the lines and the bot could process them apart. I didn't know about the publisher-consumer term, I'll look into it, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can share state between two (or more) threads without using static fields.  For example:

```
    public class State {
        private final Queue queue = ...
        private final Object somethingElse =
        // getters and setters
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        State state = ...
        new thread(new IRC(state)).start();
        new thread(new Bot(state)).start();
    }
```

Then define `IRC` and `Bot` classes to implement `Runnable` and provide them with constructors that take a `State` instance as an argument.  Of course, operations on the shared state need to be suitably synchronized.